# After opening PDF with intent, app crashes with NullPointerException

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

I have a app that shows a ListView with several documents (DOC, PDF, PPT...). Selection one of them, I use the following code to show the document:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(outFile).toString());
String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("") || mimetype == null) {
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(outFile), "text/*");
} else {
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(outFile), mimetype);            
}
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an Application:"));
```

That works fine for the the first document selected, Polaris Office opens and show the document - fine. When switching back for selecting the next document, my application is not on the last screen shown, instead it starts again. Selecting the document works and open fine in Polaris. When now switching back, the app crashes with Unable to start activity ...MainActivity ... NullPointerExpetion.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Here the LogCat:

```
 10-25 10:07:43.476: D/AndroidRuntime(8396): Shutting down VM
 10-25 10:07:43.476: W/dalvikvm(8396): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught    exception (group=0x415092a0)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.astrex.ppastrex/com.astrex.ppastrex.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at com.astrex.ppastrex.FrameDocumentos.onCreateView(FrameDocumentos.java:66)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1877)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:552)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1178)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5173)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2070)
 10-25 10:07:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8396):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post your LogCat error ?

Comment: What's the null pointer exception point to ? Odds are your problem is in your onResume() code, as your "pick the app to view this file" code looks correct..

Comment: K5 User: onResume() is not called. When coming back to my app, only onCreate() is called, than crash

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue happening for me on Android 6.0, but not in 4.4, so for older devices, it would work fine and there would be no crash.

In my case, I was downloading a url, saving the file and opening them in 3rd party viewers.

I've discovered that as long as I save the pdf to the Downloads Directory, it fixes it for my situation.

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath());
if (dir.exists() == false) {
      dir.mkdirs();
}
String fileName = "filename.pdf";
file = new File(dir, fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
 File file = new File(pdfpath);

 if (file.exists()) {
     Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

     try {
       startActivity(intent);
       finish();
     } 
     catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The intent looks like it was called correctly it works for some.  Seems like you'd have a null reference without checking if the file exists.

**Experience tells me the null comes because your device ran out of memory while opening the pdf file so your app was shut down to free up some memory.**

The solution is to add the savedinstancestate method saving what your app needs and check if the savedinstancestate != null in your oncreate method then recreate what your app needs from the savedinstancestate.

Comment: Found a strange behavior. When running on Samsung Galaxy Tab 7" with 4.1.1 I am getting the before mentioned error. But when running on Samsung Galaxy III mini with 4.1.2, it works perfect.

Comment: It's like a memory thing.  The same problem may manifest itself on a rotation change horz-vert where you save state in the  savedinstancestate then restore it in oncreate bundle.